# How to get possible values of an entity field in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I created and maintain a little bundle to serialize Symfony2 `Symfony\Component\Form\Form` objects.

When I have a entity field in a formType, I would like to get the possible values for this field.

For example : If I have a form for the entity `spaceship`, with an entity field for the destination, which is a `planet` object.

With `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::createView()`, I would get a variable which will result in a `<select>` tag which multiple choices using `form_widget()`.

What I want to know is : how, in a PHP service, can I get this set of possible values ? I tried `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::getData()` and other similar functions on the form and his entity field child, but it doesn't return to me the set of values in my database.

Does anyone know the way to get these values ?

(PS: sorry for my poor english.)

EDIT: As asked, the part of my bundle which is used to serialize a form object :

```
<?php
namespace WTech\FormBundle\Transformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class FormTransformer
{
    /** @var Request **/
    private $request;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request->getMasterRequest();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function serializeForm(Form $form)
    {
        $fields = array_keys($form->all());
        $nbFields = count($fields);
        $config = $form->getConfig();

        $attributes = $config->getOptions();
        // Building the basic Form data
        $data = [
            'name' => $form->getName(),
            'action' => $this->buildAction($config->getAction()),
            'method' => $config->getMethod(),
            'attributes' => $attributes,
            'children' => [],
            'csrf' => $this->buildCsrfToken($config)
        ];

        // Look over the form fields
        for($i = 0; $i < $nbFields; ++$i)
        {
            $field = $form->get($fields[$i]);
            $children = $field->all();

            // If there is children, we ignore the current field (type repeated)
            // And we build the children fields
            if(count($children) > 0)
            {
                $this->addChildrenToFields($data, $field->getConfig()->getName(), $children);
                continue;
            }
            $this->buildField($data, $field);
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addChildrenToFields(&$data, $parentName, $children)
    {
        reset($children);

        while($key = key($children))
        {
            $this->buildField($data, $children[$key], "[$parentName]");
            next($children);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildField(&$data, $field, $parentName = '')
    {
        $name = $field->getName();
        $key = "{$parentName}[{$name}]";
        $config = $field->getConfig();
        $type = $config->getType()->getInnerType()->getName();

        $attributes = $config->getOptions();
        $data['children'][$key] = [
            'type' => $type,
            'label' => $this->buildLabel($name, $attributes),
            'label_class' => $this->buildLabelClass($attributes),
            'div_class' => $this->buildDivClass($attributes),
            'class' => $this->buildClass($attributes),
            'translation_domain' => $this->buildTranslationDomain($attributes)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildAction($primaryAction)
    {
        return
            (!empty($primaryAction))
            ? $primaryAction
            : $this->request->getPathInfo()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildLabel($name, $attributes)
    {
        return
            (isset($attributes['label']))
            ? $attributes['label']
            : $name
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildLabelClass($attributes)
    {
        return
            (isset($attributes['attr']['label_class']))
            ? $attributes['attr']['label_class']
            : ''
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildDivClass($attributes)
    {
        return
            (isset($attributes['attr']['div_class']))
            ? $attributes['attr']['div_class']
            : ''
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildClass($attributes)
    {
        return
            (isset($attributes['attr']['class']))
            ? $attributes['attr']['class']
            : ''
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildTranslationDomain($attributes)
    {
        return
            (isset($attributes['translation_domain']))
            ? $attributes['translation_domain']
            : ''
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildCsrfToken(FormConfigInterface $config)
    {
        if($config->hasOption('csrf_provider'))
        {
            return [
                'token' => $config->getOption('csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken($config->getOption('intention')),
                'field_name' => "{$config->getName()}[{$config->getOption('csrf_field_name')}]"
            ];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly: the list of `planet` entities is dependant on the `spaceship` entity and you want to know how to change the planets depending on the spaceship, right?

Comment: not really, I must have explained it a bit bad. I want to serialize the whole speceship Form. In the spaceship entity, I have a relationship between spaceships and planets with my ORM, so in the Form I have an entity field, such as described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

My question is, how to get the data, If I have for example Earth and Pluto in my database as possible values. These values are known by Twig when he renders the form, so it is stored somewhere, but I don't know where. I just need this information to retrieve, in PHP, the values

Comment: Wait, so you want to serialize the form and not the model data, am I correct? Do you want to serialize the view?

Comment: No, I considered that way of doing it, but I thought serializing the Form object itself would be better. So yes, this is the form I am trying to serialize :) !

Comment: Then if you're using, say, `createFormBuilder()`, you should call the serializer after you call `getForm()`, or whenever you have your `Form` object. It's not difficult, considering the documentation of [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php).

Comment: This is already done ! I have my bundle [here](https://github.com/Kern046/WTechFormBundle). I can serialize the form and build it from JSON, but for entity fields, I'm not able to build the ``<select>`` tag with the options because I don't know how to get them from the form !

Comment: Now I think I understand this way better. Can you please post how you are serializing/deserializing a form? Because `entity` form types are just a subtype of a `choice` form type.

Comment: Try this: if among the options you find `choices`, then render as a select and fill it with the data in the choices list. This is valid for both `choice` and `entity` types.

Comment: Very very nice :D ! I found it in the options, like you suggested ! There was a 'choice_list' option, returning a ``Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList`` object with the values I was looking for ! Thanks you for your great support !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the solution is pretty simple. The `entity` form type has a `choice_list` option returning a `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList` object. This will enable you to find the values that are stored in the form type after they are loaded from the database.